# Custom dropdown field not populated when selecting contact on contribution page

Tags: custom-fields

I have an issue with special custom fields

I am logged in as admin on public contribution page on front end.

I click on "not Mister XXX XXX"

Then I choose the user I want to renew.

The text fields are well populated with information from database
But the dropdown fields and date fields are not populated.

I would like to know if this a known issue of CiviCRM or how to fix it ?
It's seem to be a ajax issue ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may be wanting to renew the membership of another person as an administrator. To do that you should use a backend form rather than the front end one which has "not Mister XXX XXX". One way to do this is to find the contact to renew, click on their Membership tab on the Contact Summary page, then beside the membership to renew click More > Renew.